# Wowza RTSP stream authentication

Tags: video, video-streaming, rtsp, wowza

Does anyone know how to set a password to a Wowza RTSP stream?

Now I can use the stream `rtsp://127.0.0.1:1935/live/mystream` but I want something like `rtsp://username:password@:127.0.0.1:1935/live/mystream`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting  to digest for the live's application.xml and set your username/password in the /conf/publish.password

Note - there are two different settings - PlayMethod and PublishMethod. If you're trying to secure playback, you'll want to use digest on the PlayMethod as well.

Answer (score 0):

I know [WMSPanel](https://wmspanel.com/features) has stream protection feature in their roadmap for Wowza. It should be easy to implement via custom Wowza agent.